# Need to Supervised and UNSupervised Programmatically In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to detect programatically if an iOS device is supervised .Any help would be beneficial .

Comment: You can't.  Supervision can only be enabled or disabled by connecting physically to a Mac running Apple Configurator 2 or by enrolling the device in the Device Enrolment Program and enforcing MDM enrolment.

Comment: But there is one app name "safelagoon"
https://safelagoon.com/en/ In this be didn't need to connect physically with mac or any system.

Comment: That app cannot establish supervised mode on an iOS device.  Supervision is a specific hardware state that can only be applied to an erased device.  You may be talking about enrolling an MDM management profile, which is different although related.  MDM profiles can enforce more settings on a supervised device

Answer (score 1):

What's your use case for checking for supervision? So far, there is no way for an application to check programmatically as there is no clear use case for it. Supervision is used when trying to install profiles with payloads that require supervision or when trying to initiate autonomous single app mode from within an app. In the former case, the MDM server can query supervision, as you've stated. In the latter case of autonomous single app mode, you don't particularly care about supervision, you care about whether you were able to successfully get in or out of autonomous single app mode and the completion block allows you to check that (though you should probably have a message pop up to users if it fails to get you for the users to check that the device is supervised).

Would love to hear what the use case would be and if you have one, you may want to submit this as an enhancement request to Apple